# Como realizar un ejecutable en Visual Fox Pro 9.0

Tags: base-de-datos, visual-foxpro

Como puedo crear un ejecutable en VFox Pro 9.0, tengo este código pero solo lo puedo ejecutar una vez un después ya no.

De igual forma solo lo puedo abrir con VFox Pro instalado.

Adjunto parte del código:

```
SET TALK OFF
CLEAR 
DO FORM formcitas
READ EVENTS
```

Saludos y Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

no comprendo bien la inquietud que tienes pues según las instrucciones que anotas, el programa ejecutable debe funcionar corectamente hasta que dentro de formcitas o cualquier otro formulario tengas una instrucción CLEAR EVENTS.

Debes verfificar si tal vez ocultas el SCREEN de VFP que es donde generalemnte se ejecuta nuestro proyecto, confirmalo si tienes alguna de las siguientes instrucciones en tu código:
_SCREEN.Visible = .F. 
o
application.Visible = .F.

Igualmente verifica el config.fpw si tienes SCREEN=OFF.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes de definir las variables públicas en caso de que existan, luego definir un programa de inicio, una ves hecho esto debes de definir la variable pública de conexión a un servidor de datos externos según sea el caso. ejemplo

```
`_SCREEN.caption` = Nombre del sistema'
 `_SCREEN.windowstate = 2` **el estado de la pantalla al iniciar***
 `_SCREEN.icon` = 'C:\dirección de alguún icono que le quieras porner a tu ejecutable' 
 `_SCREEN.closable = .F.` **indica que el sistema se va a cerrar desde un form**
` SET SYSMENU OFF`
 `SET STATUS BAR OFF`
 `SET TALK OFF`
 `SET RESOURCE OFF` 
 `SET NOTIFY ON`
 `SET SAFETY OFF`
 `SET DATE TO DMY`
 `SET CENTURY ON`

***aquí los detalles de tu formulario de incio***
 `IF !LEFT(VERSION(),16)=='Visual 07'
    SET ENGINEBEHAVIOR 70
 ENDIF`
 `DO FORM` **tu formulario de inicio***
 `READ EVENTS`
 `SET SYSMENU TO DEFAULT`
 `SET DEFAULT TO`
 `MODIFY WINDOW screen`
 `CLOSE DATABASES ALL`
 `SET HELP TO`
 `SET DELETED OFF`
 `ON SHUTDOWN QUIT`
 `SET TALK ON`
 `SET STATUS BAR ON`
 `RETURN`
`ENDPROC`
```

**luego los seteadores del formulario que y pantalla de inicio**

```
`SET STATUS BAR OFF`
 `SET DEFAULT TO` ****puedes poner o no la variable de conexión**
`SET EXACT ON`
 `SET NEAR ON`
 `SET LOCK OFF`
 `SET TALK OFF`
 `SET ESCAPE OFF`
 `SET SYSFORMATS ON`
 `_SCREEN.caption =` 'El nombre de tu sistema'
 `_SCREEN.windowstate = 0`
 `_SCREEN.Icon` = 'C:\icono que representará a la aplicación'
 `SET SYSMENU OFF`
 `SET DELETED ON`
 `CLOSE DATABASES ALL`
 `SET CENTURY ON`
 `SET NOTIFY OFF`
 `SET RESOURCE OFF` 
 `SET STATUS BAR OFF`
 `SET SAFETY OFF`
 `SET PATH TO &mdir` **aqui defines la salida de archivos segú sea el caso**
 `SET DECIMALS TO 2`
 `SET MULTILOCKS ON`
 `SET REPROCESS TO 1`
 `RETURN`
`ENDPROC`
```

Espero te sirva amigo.

Answer (score 0):

en mi caso se debia establecer el elemento que se crea en la pestaña CODIGO, como ESTABLECER PRINCIPAL, eso se logra presionando CLICK DERECHO sobre este elemento

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]